# Deploying typescript/nodejs project

Tags: node.js, typescript, webpack

i want to run https://gitlab.com/jmis/exilecraft on my own linux server, sadly there is no documentation aboout it and i can't reach the author.

I'm completly new to nodejs, typescript, webpack etc. 
But this is what i figured out:

i need npm, webpack, webpack-dev-server

i had to change package.json and remove all "^" so i can 
npm install
without any dependencies and compatibility problems, all modules are now installed in minimal required version.

There is a script "start" and after runing it the site is responding, there is some loading, site turns gray and then nothing.

Almost the same as www.exilecraft.org (original site) before showing any content.
I see tsconfig.json there so i understand that this is a typescript project.

I need some directions how to make it work?